# Plotting a igraph network with DiagrammeR

Tags: r, plot, igraph, diagrammer

I would like to create this simple igraph plot:

```
library(igraph)
mydata <- data.table(from=c("John", "John", "Jim"),to=c("John", "Jim", "Jack"))
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mydata, directed=T)
plot(mygraph, vertex.label.dist=2)
```

[image]

With diagrammeR

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mygraph2 <- from_igraph(mygraph)
grViz(mygraph2)
```

Produces this error

> Error in file.exists(diagram) : invalid 'file' argument

I've also tried with

```
grViz(readLines(mygraph2))
```

and other combinations or the command plot() but I can't find the proper way.

How can I do it?

I've openen a new question to get the same result directly with DiagrammeR, without igraph:

[How to create a network graph with DiagrammeR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749930/how-to-create-a-network-graph-with-diagrammer)

Comment: Do you want `render_graph` ?

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a couple of things going on.

```
library(igraph)
library(DiagrammeR)

mydata <- data.table(from=c("John", "John", "Jim"),to=c("John", "Jim", "Jack"))
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mydata, directed=TRUE)
```

The following code throws an warning

```
mygraph2 <- from_igraph(mygraph)
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: In data.frame(from = as.integer(igraph::ends(igraph, igraph::E(igraph))[,  :
>     NAs introduced by coercion

And if you look at `mygraph2` there is no node or edge info, and it doesnt render : `render_graph(mygraph2)`. But the warning is informative as it points to the lines of code ( `as.integer(ends(mygraph, E(mygraph), names=TRUE))` : maybe we want names=FALSE) , so try removing names , but set labels

```
V(mygraph)$label = V(mygraph)$name
V(mygraph)$name = factor(V(mygraph)$name, levels=as.character(V(mygraph)$name))
```

No warning and renders

```
mygraph2 <- from_igraph(mygraph)
render_graph(mygraph2)
```

If you want to see the `dot` code you can use `generate_dot` , and then pass this to `grViz`, however, this is what `render_graph` is doing.

```
grViz(generate_dot(mygraph2))
```

Comment: Is it better to do it like this or trying to create the graph directly with Diagrammer, without igraph?

Comment: I need to create graphs from large datasets. I've first tried using igraph because it places the nodes automatically in a nice location. It was what I've read in a tutorial. But I don't know what advantage or dissadvantage could have either method. Though the fewer packages I use the better, maybe I don't need the igraph step.

Comment: well if your graphs are large then automatically generating the graphs rather than typing out the graphviz code will be useful (i didnt know of `generate_dot` so i may use this myself to generate initial graphviz code, which i can then alter manually)

Comment: What would be the command to generate the graph directly from "mydata" (a data.frame with columns "from" and "to")?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your process.

The first one is in the command `from_igraph`. I'm not sure, maybe it's a bug in the package, maybe it's a problem with my setting, but I couldn't use it to get the desired result. The following works on my machine.

```
mygraph3 <- from_adj_matrix(as.matrix(get.adjacency(mygraph)), mode = "directed")
```

And then you need `render_graph` or something like that to get your graph, `grViz` is for string representation of graph, not for graph itself.

```
render_graph(mygraph3)
```

Comment: If we compare the result of your method with user20650's method, your's doesn't produce arrows.

Comment: set `mode="directed"` in `from_adj_matrix`

Comment: @skan I corrected for that mistake in my post. To have a directed graph generated from adjacent matrix, the argument `mode` has to be set to "directed", and then it will give you the directed graph. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: What would be the command to generate the graph directly from "mydata" (a data.frame with columns "from" and "to")?

Comment: Also adding the labels inside the nodes would be great.

Comment: @skan It seems that DiagrammeR doesn't provide function to transform data.frame to graph. So if you want to transform data.frame to DiagrammeR graph, the only way is through igraph.

Comment: I've updated my question with my trial to get the graph just with DiagrammeR.